# Galaxy S6 High RAM usage

Tags: android-5.1.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy

We have developed an Android app and we do have some serious memory problems on the Samsung Galaxy S6.
I have read about problems with memory-leak and bad memory management in the early days of the S6. I have also read that these problems should have been solved. The phone we're testing is running 5.1.1 and is fully updated.

Our app is a rather small app, it normally consumes 29 MB of RAM on most Android phones. On the Galaxy S6 it consumes 4-8 times more memory. To display a single 512 x 512 bitmap, the app consumes 16 MB. The splash screen alone takes 60 MB.

Are anyone familiar with some workaround, so we can keep the memory footprint at normal level? Or is just very bad software from Google/Samsung we have to live with?

Kind regards
Freddy

Answer (score 0):

That is unusual activity. try factory resetting the phone.